# Refer to item from foreign key

Tags: python, sql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Using Flask-SQLAlchemy, I have database models like so:

```
class subjects(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    subject = db.Column(db.String(100))
    color = db.Column(db.Integer)

    def __init__(self, subject):
        self.subject = subject

class questions(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    subject = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('subjects.id'))
    question = db.Column(db.String(500), nullable=True)


    def __init__(self, subject, question):
        self.subject = subject
        self.question = question
```

As you may see, in the `questions` class, you can see the column `subject` refers to the `id` column of `subjects`.

Is there a way so that if I was to refer to `questions.subject` or something like that instead of returning the `id` of the subjects class, it would return the `subject` of the subjects class instead?

Also, the `subject` column in `subjects` will not be unique so I cannot create a foreign key using that column. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLAlchemy's `relationship()` function is what you're after. First, rename `questions.subject` to `questions.subject_id`, then create a new `subject` attribute, using the `relationship()` function, like so:

```
class questions(db.Model):
    subject_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('subjects.id'))
    subject = db.relationship("subjects")
    ... etc ...
```

You can also use the `backref` arguments on the relationship to create a 'back-reference' from a `questions` instance to all its `subjects`. For more details, head to the following docs:

- [Flask-SQLAlchemy tutorial](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.0/models/#one-to-many-relationships)
- [SQLAlchemy relationships tutorial](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/tutorial.html#orm-tutorial-relationship)
- [SQLAlchemy relationship documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/relationships.html)